# Identificar si una etiqueta es valida o no usando un cierto criterio y las librerias <stdio.h> y <string.h>

Tags: c

Estoy intentando resolver un problema en lenguage c, pero no puedo llegar a entender como completarlo. Resolvi parte de ello pero me falta la parte más dificil y quisiera comprender como podria.

Si necesitan que aclare algo me dejan saber, porfavor.

> **La ciudad de Yakarta ha sido rodeada por los atacantes. Un trailer entra en la ciudad. El conductor afirma que la carga es comida y medicinas de los indonesios. Ali Asmath es uno de los soldados en Bekasi. Duda sobre el trailer, tal vez sea del equipo rival.**

> **Ali sabe que una etiqueta es válida si la suma de cada dos dígitos consecutivos de la misma es par y su letra no es una vocal.**

> **Determina si la etiqueta del camión es válida o no.**

> **Para este problema consideramos que las letras "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y" son vocales.**

> **Crear un programa que le ayude a soldados como Ali, a controlar el acceso correctamente.**

Con esto podemos saber cual es el criterio y que se tiene que poder hacer.

Criterio:

- La etiqueta debe contener una letra
- La letra no puede ser una de las vocales consideradas: "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y"
- La letra puede estar en cualquier posicion de la etiqueta
- La suma de cada dos numeros consecutivos deben ser par: 1 + 1 = 2, 3 + 3 = 6
- No especifica la longitud de la etiqueta pero no influeye tanto en el criterio de todas formas

Que hara el programa:

- El usuario puede ingregsar la etiqueta en forma de cadena ya que va a contener una letra. Ejemplos: C789638 o 71C9108 o 20C91
- Identificar si la etiqueta contiene alguna letra que sea de las vocales, si contiene una no es valida la etiqueta. Tomando en cuenta que la letra puede estar en cualquier posicion de la etiqueta.
- Verificar que la suma de cada dos numeros consecutivos sea par, si no es asi, la etiqueta es invalida.

Por ejemplo: C789628 - No es Valida, ya que entre los numeros, no todas las sumas de cada dos numeros pares.

- 7 + 8 = 15 (impar)
- 9 + 6 = 15 (impar)
- 2 + 8 = 10 (par)

Un ejemplo que si seria valido seria: 20C91

- 2 + 0 = 2 (par)
- 9 + 1 = 10 (par)

Con esto tambien podemos saber que la longitud de la cadena debe ser impar para que pueda haber una suma apropiada entre dos numeros consecutivos. Ya que no se cuenta la letra y de tal forma sera una longitud par al no contar la letra.

Por ejemplo si tenemos una etiqueta como, 9C91, solo podra haber una suma entre los dos numeros al final, "9 y 1 pero el "9" al inicio no tendra una suma.

- C789628 (Longitud = 7 y se quita la C, (7 - 1) = longitud = 6)
- 20C91 (Longitud = 5 y se quita la C, (5 - 1) = longitud = 4)

Con esto creamos otro paso que se debe tomar en cuenta antes de verificar la suma de dos numeros consecutivos

- Verificar si la longitud de la cadena es impar o par, si es par se le deja saber al usuario que las placas solo pueden ser de una longitud impar (7, 9, 11, etc.)

Ahora con todo esto tomado en cuenta quiero dejarles saber que no solo consideren este criterio, tambien si identifican otras cosas al leer el problema me dejan saber.

Otra cosa que quiero dejar clara es que solo puedo usar las siguientes funciones:
Funciones en la libreria <string.h> y <stdio.h>

Puedo usar: if, else if, else, scanf(), gets(), getchar(), puts(), char, int, float, double

y en la libreria <string.h>:

- strlen()
- strcat
- strncat()
- strcpy()
- strncpy()
- strcmp()
- strncmp()
- strchr()
- strrchr()
- strstr()
- strcspn()
- strspn()
- strpbrk()
- strtok()

Si por alguna razón debo usar algo más que esté en alguna de esas liberias, me dejan saber porfavor y si me podrian presentar un codigo que resuelva este problema sería de gran ayuda, ya que debo averiguar como hacerlo hoy mismo. He intentado varias cosas y no sé que más pensar. Solo he podido completar la parte de identificar si hay alguna de las vocales consideradas.

Actualización:
Pude resolver el problema de una diferente forma pero aun me gustaria saber como lo resolverian ustedes solo usando mayormente cadenas.

Aqui esta la forma en que lo resolvi:

```
/*
Título: Revisión de Etiqueta
Nombre: Naresh Pillay
Fecha: 15/05/2022
*/

//Inclusión de Liberias
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  //Variables Locales
  const char vocales[] = "AEIOUY";
  char letra[2];
  int n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6;
  char* res_letras;
  int suma1;
  int suma2;
  int suma3;

  //Instrucciones a Soldado para ingresar la etiqueta del vehiculo
  printf("\nEscriba la etiqueta del vehiculo. Escribala usando un espacio entre cada caracter.\n\n");

  printf("Asegurese que al terminar de escribir la etiqueta presione ENTER en el teclado.\n\n");

  printf("Deben haber 7 caracteres en su etiqueta. Debe iniciar con la letra que le corresponda y que sea mayuscula.\n\n");

  printf("Siga el ejemplo: [ D 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]\n\n");

  //Ingreso de etiqueta
  printf("ETIQUETA DEL VEHICULO: ");
  scanf("%s%d%d%d%d%d%d", letra,&n1,&n2,&n3,&n4,&n5,&n6);

  //Impresión de etiqueta ingresada
  printf("\n\nLa etiqueta es: [ %s %d %d %d %d %d %d ]\n\n", letra, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6);

    //Comparación de letra en etiqueta con vocales las cuales no estan permitidas
    res_letras = strpbrk(vocales, letra);

    //Calculos de sumas entre dos numeros consecutivos
    suma1 = n1 + n2;
    suma2 = n3 + n4;
    suma3 = n5 + n6;

  //Revision de criterio para validar la etiqueta (Condiciones) e impresiones de resultados
  if(res_letras) {
    printf("********************************************************\n");
    printf("*LA ETIQUETA NO ES VÁLIDA!! NO DEJE AL VEHICULO PASAR!!*\n");
    printf("********************************************************\n\n\n");

    printf("********************************************************\n");
    printf("************** ESTÁ PRESENTE LA VOCAL: %c ***************\n", *res_letras);
    printf("********************************************************\n\n\n");

  } else if (suma1 %2 != 0) {
    printf("********************************************************\n");
    printf("*LA ETIQUETA NO ES VÁLIDA!! NO DEJE AL VEHICULO PASAR!!*\n");
    printf("********************************************************\n\n\n");

    printf("**********************************************************\n");
    printf("*LA PRIMERA SUMA ENTRE DOS NUMEROS CONSECUTIVOS NO ES PAR*\n");
    printf("**********************************************************\n\n\n");
    printf("La letra en la etiqueta es: [%s] (NO VOCAL)\n\n", letra);
    printf("Primera Suma = [%d] (IMPAR)\n\n", suma1);

      } else if (suma2 %2 != 0) {
        printf("********************************************************\n");
        printf("*LA ETIQUETA NO ES VÁLIDA!! NO DEJE AL VEHICULO PASAR!!*\n");
        printf("********************************************************\n\n\n");

        printf("**********************************************************\n");
        printf("*LA SEGUNDA SUMA ENTRE DOS NUMEROS CONSECUTIVOS NO ES PAR*\n");
        printf("**********************************************************\n\n\n");
          printf("La letra en la etiqueta es: [%s] (NO VOCAL)\n\n", letra);
          printf("Primera Suma = [%d] (PAR)\n\n", suma1);
          printf("Segunda Suma = [%d] (IMPAR)\n\n", suma2);

        } else if (suma3 %2 != 0) {
            printf("********************************************************\n");
            printf("*LA ETIQUETA NO ES VÁLIDA!! NO DEJE AL VEHICULO PASAR!!*\n");
            printf("********************************************************\n\n\n");

            printf("**********************************************************\n");
            printf("*LA TERCERA SUMA ENTRE DOS NUMEROS CONSECUTIVOS NO ES PAR*\n");
            printf("**********************************************************\n\n\n");
            printf("La letra en la etiqueta es: [%s] (NO VOCAL)\n\n", letra);
            printf("Primera Suma = [%d] (PAR)\n\n", suma1);
            printf("Segunda Suma = [%d] (PAR)\n\n", suma2);
            printf("Tercera Suma = [%d] (IMPAR)\n\n", suma3);

            } else {
                printf("**************************************************\n");
                printf("*LA ETIQUETA ES VÁLIDA!! DEJE AL VEHICULO PASAR!!*\n");
                printf("**************************************************\n\n\n");

                printf("******************************************\n");
                printf("*La etiqueta válida es: [ %s %d %d %d %d %d %d ]*\n", letra, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6);
                printf("******************************************\n\n\n");

                printf("La letra en la etiqueta es: [%s] (NO VOCAL)\n\n", letra);
                printf("Primera Suma = [%d] (PAR)\n\n", suma1);
                printf("Segunda Suma = [%d] (PAR)\n\n", suma2);
                printf("Tercera Suma = [%d] (PAR)\n\n", suma3);
        }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Deberías agregar el código que llevas, si no asumiremos que solo estas esperando que te resolvamos la tarea, y pueden cerrarte la pregunta. Si añades código obtendrás ayuda más fácilmente.

Comment: Listo! Gracias!

Comment: Signos de puntuación, espacio – ¿existen? Y cuando sí, ¿ignorar?

Comment: A propósito: `gets` *no* es seguro y ademas a sido removido del éstandar C desde C11, ya no se debería utilizar. Hay `fgets` junto con `stdin` en su lugar.

Comment: `scanf("%s%d%d%d%d%d%d", letra,&n1,&n2,&n3,&n4,&n5,&n6);` no hará lo que esperas, aceptará todo como `grmblbrmbl 1210, 77, 333, 51, 54, 20102012` – lo que necesitas solo es un unico "%s" para el codigo entero (asumiendo que espacio no es válido).